# Horizontal scroll view not scrolling

Tags: ios

I've just vertical scrolling a few times in the past, but now I'm trying to implement horizontal scrolling but when I run it it doesn't scroll.

What is the problem with it?

[image]

P.S. is it possible to design and layout views using a storyboard for scrolling? In this example the blue view is still visible within the screen representation, so its ok to deal with, but suppose I wanted to add another view which is further to the right and thus not visible within the screen representation? Is there anyway of visually designing a scroll view where you can see all the entirity within the storyboard what it will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a trailing constraint on the scroll view's direct subview, so the scroll view cannot compute the correct `contentSize`.

Also, it's easier to understand the constraints in the document outline if you give each view a unique label. You have two views labelled “View” so it's difficult to be sure which constraints connect to which “View”.

Comment: I presume a trialing constraint for for the right edge of the blue view? But how can one be added, because the blue view is off the screen so there's nothing to hook it up to to add a constraint? I added names and re-added the picture